# Why is my Android button not updating variable? Am I using startActivityForResult incorrectly?

Tags: android, button, gps, actionbarsherlock

I have created a button that checks if the GPS setting is turned on. If it is OFF, it displays the settings menu, if it is ON it just shows a toast message. The button listener code is inside the `onCreateView` method.

The app is created with ActionBarSherlock tabs.

If the user presses the button, the correct action happens the first time. If the GPS is OFF and the user changes the setting to turn it ON and then presses the button again, the `enabled` variable is not updated.

If I select another tab, and then return to this one, the variable updates OK.

I think what I need to do is reload the Fragment (which I wanted to avoid). I considered changing the variable as the Settings intent is opened, but this would cause a problem if the user just closed its without toggling the GPS on. Is there a better or more correct way of forcing this variable to update with each button press?

Code:

```
     final Button butGPS =(Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.btnGPS);
     butGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean enabled  = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GPS settings
                if (!enabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Turn On GPS!",1).show()  ;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "GPS is ON!",1).show()  ;
                }
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined your `onClickListener` has `enabled` being initialized only once, when the Listener is created. What you want is to reinitialize the value in `onClick` in order to always get the updated value:

```
 final Button butGPS =(Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.btnGPS);
 butGPS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean enabled  = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GPS settings
            if (!enabled) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Turn On GPS!",1).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "GPS is ON!",1).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

By the way, I'm not sure what you're trying to do aside from open up the Setting to enable GPS, but unless you're expecting to receive a result from the Settings screen, and you also overrode the `onActivityResult()` method, then you don't need to call `startActivityForResult()`, you could just call `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Thanks for your time, at this moment in time, all I was looking for was to open the settings and enable GPS, so as you say, I should just call startActivity. I have solved the problem by Overriding the onResume method and reinitialising the variable in there.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you initialize your `onClickListener` in `onCreate()`, updating the value in `onResume()` would mean that you need a global variable to persist the value (in order to use it again in `onClick()`). You're better off doing the way I suggested to keep the scope minimal, unless you have other locations that will use it, which it doesn't sound like you do.

Comment: yes, I did make the variable global, I will give your method a try now

Comment: Thanks again, that is implemented perfectly now, really simple, I should have got that one.